# Force form value and lock it / PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I'd like to have a formfield prepopulated and locked, so that no autocomplete or user meddling could ever change it. After doing research, I found out that serverside scripting is the way to go. So, PHP seems to be the way to go.

I've attempted to search Google and SO, but I can't get the hang of this. An example from my code:

```
function change_set_checkout_field_input_value_default($fields) {
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['default'] = 'abc';
return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_set_checkout_field_input_value_default' );
```

This example is for WordPress/WooCommerce. It works, but only as far as there is nothing interfering with the field. I want to user to be able to see the field as filled (but greyed out beyond meddling), so disabling the fields and sending the data in some other way, at least to me, doesn't seem feasible.

How do I advance in prepopulating AND locking the field?

Thank you.

Comment: Use html attribute autocomplete="off" and readonly

Comment: Thank you! The readony-approach seems nice, although it is completely reversable by just removing the attribute with a dev console or so. 

Of autocomplete: I'm using "autocomplete=null", because "off" will be interpreted by some browsers and turned, by the browser, into whatever it likes, thus enabling autocomplete. If the value is something else, like "banana", the browser will not be able to interpret it and thus leaves it alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html attribute `readonly` on each input. Here's the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-readonly

Comment: Thank you. Didn't think it would be that simple; although this leaves the field for anyone with access and knowledge of the dev console to just erase the readonly bit from the code and be able to change the field value. Maybe what I'm looking for isn't doable - which is absolutely lock a form field serverside, so that users cannot meddle with it without hacking the server.

But yeah, maybe it's a stupid idea to begin with - the form would become sort of an app, which validates all user request upon entry. x)